# Design Pattern for processing method result

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am currently refactoring a piece of code to keep things testable and maintainable in our c# application.

I've stumbled upon a scenario where an existing method returns data with lists and enums that is then processed with lots of if else conditions in a big long method that is 800+ lines long.  Lucky me!

I was trying to pick a suitable design pattern from the Gang Of Four, but cannot see something that fits.  I will outline what I have in place at the minute.  Any ideas on how to best tackle/refactor the following?

The following code has been simplified from what I have in production.  Its purpose is to show the cut down logic in the scenario.  This is what I have refactored to so far.  Don't worry about statics and that there are no interfaces - interfaces have been omitted for simplicity.

```
public class MySearchClass
{
    public static SearchResult Find(QueryParameters queryParams)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class SearchEntityResult
{
    public IEnumerable<SearchEntityData> Matches { get; set; }
}

public class SearchEntityData
{
    public SearchMatchType MatchType { get; set; }
    public Guid SearchEntityId { get; set; }
    public string EntityName { get; set; }
}

public enum SearchMatchType
{
    Partial,
    Exact   
}


public class BigLongMethodClassProcessor
{
    public static void DoFindAndProcess()
    {
        ... spaghetti code ...

        SearchEntityResult result = MySearchClass.Find(...);

        if (result.BestMatch == SearchMatchType.Exact)
        {
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var m in  result.Matches)
            {
                if (m.MatchType == SearchMatchType.Partial)
                {
                    ... do this ...
                }
                else if (m.MatchType == SearchMatchType.Exact)
                {
                    ... do that ...
                }
            }   
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

My thoughts was to have a factory that would look at the SearchEntityResult and create an appropriate SearchEntityResultProcessor.

```
public class ExactSearchEntityResultProcessor : ISearchEntityResultProcessor
{
    public void Process(SearchEntityResult result)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class SearchEntityResultProcessorFactory
{
    public static ISearchEntityResultProcessor Create(SearchEntityResult result)
    {
        if (result.BestMatch == SearchMatchType.Exact)
        {
            return new ExactSearchEntityResultProcessor();
        }
        else if (result.BestMatch == SearchMatchType.Partial)
        {
            return new PartialSearchEntityResultProcessor();
        }
        else
        {
            // throw
        }
    }
}
```

So BigLongMethodClassProcessor will look like:

```
public class BigLongMethodClassProcessor
{
    public static void DoFindAndProcess()
    {           
        SearchEntityResult result = MySearchClass.Find(...);
        ISearchEntityResultProcessor processor = SearchEntityResultProcessorFactory.Create(result);
        processor.Process(result);
    }
}
```

Then all statics will be removed and interfaces introduced.

Comment: Keep in mind that Patterns aren't a buffet of solutions - they are documentation tools. They can't fix anything! I recommend trying to understand the possibilities of your language first and drawing your own conclusions about how to solve this instead of looking for a magic formula for that. They are not finished designs. Instead, look at them as how other people solved their problems and think about yours in a more critical way.

Comment: Re-factor your code using the Hollywood Principle and use the Command Pattern with each of your Processor class being Commands.

Comment: "interface introduced" is not an inherent advantage, but a disadvantage, unless the interface is needed. The same is true for all superfluous abstractions.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution looks good to me. You are constructing the processor that can handle a result then processing that result using it.

Another option is the chain of responsibility pattern.
http://www.dofactory.com/net/chain-of-responsibility-design-pattern

This is like your solution except the check for whether a processor can handle the result is contained within the processor itself. Then you'd just have a list of all processors and pass the result to each in turn until one of them was able to process it. That way if a new processor is developed it just needs to be added to the list.

Answer (score 0):

This approach doesn't look too bad.

You have one remaining section where you have a bunch of `if` statements.  If your processors are stateless, you could eliminate that by using a lookup table, like this:

```
public class SearchEntityResultProcessorFactory
{
    static private Dictionary<SearchMatchType,ISearchEntityResultProcessor > _processorLookup = new  Dictionary<SearchMatchType,ISearchEntityResultProcessor>();

    static SearchEntityResultProcessorFactory()
    {
        _processorLookup.Add(SearchMatchType.Exact, new ExactSearchEntityResultProcessor());
        _processorLookup.Add(SearchMatchType.Partial, new PartialSearchEntityResultProcessor());
    }

    public static ISearchEntityResultProcessor Create(SearchEntityResult result)
    {
        return _processorLookup[result.BestMatch];
    }
}
```

If they are not stateless, you can still do it, but have to use delegates:

```
public class SearchEntityResultProcessorFactory
{
    static private Dictionary<SearchMatchType,Func<ISearchEntityResultProcessor>> _processorLookup = new Dictionary<SearchMatchType,Func<ISearchEntityResultProcessor>>();

    static SearchEntityResultProcessorFactory()
    {
        _processorLookup.Add(SearchMatchType.Exact, () => new ExactSearchEntityResultProcessor());
        _processorLookup.Add(SearchMatchType.Partial, () => new PartialSearchEntityResultProcessor());
    }

    public static ISearchEntityResultProcessor Create(SearchEntityResult result)
    {
        return _processorLookup[result.BestMatch]();
    }
}
```